# Relativity of simultaneity & time dilation for the purposes of nonsense

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, soft-question, time-dilation

I'm a fiction writer who's tinkering around with a sci-fi project and trying to dial in how "hard" it's going to be, on a sliding scale between Clark and Kessel-run-in-parsecs. To that end I've been trying to wrap my head around what relativity means in practical (read: narrative-affecting) terms.

While there might have been a point in ages past where younger me could have crunched through it, let's just say that today I am...not equipped to chew on Lorentz transformations and have any sort of confidence in the results. (Confession: I only know what those are because I saw them on Wikipedia). So I was hoping that someone on here might be able to help me.

I have a specific thought experiment that should get me pointed in the correct-ish direction:

-You and your friend find a ~spacemagic~ stargate doorway that will instantly transport you to a planet 10 light years away (yes yes *stop throwing things I KNOW*). Your friend suits up and steps through, and you follow at a later date. Is their any relativistic effect that could, depending on the conditions, make your reunion awkward depending on how long you took to follow? If you went the next day, would your friend experience roughly the same amount of time passing on their end? How about if you waited a month, or a year?

-For example, what if your friend was on a planet that was orbiting a star much more massive than the sun? Or that was traveling at a different speed around the galaxy?

-If so, how drastic of an effect are we talking about? Would your personal watches be out of sync by minutes, days, years...?

To dash in some pop-culture, I'm trying to gauge if that near-the-black-hole-planet in *Interstellar* (where decades passed on earth while the away team was gone for hours) was an extreme edge case, or if interstellar explorers would have to deal with some degree of time dilation regularly, even if the relativity problems of near-light-speed/magically-faster-than-light travel were somehow solved (*dodges more thrown objects from angry physicists*).

Alright, that's enough out of me. Input appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start: when it comes to velocity time dilation there is an analogy with pythagoras' theorem.

Take a triangle with one very sharp corner, let's say 5 degrees. Then there is almost no difference in length between the diagonal and the long side.

Draw a parabola ( $y=x^2$ ). The line is initially hugging the x-axis.

The expression for the amount of time dilation as a function of relative velocity isn't exactly that parabola, but you get that same x-axis hugging.

Even at 0.5 the speed of light the difference in amount of proper time that elapses still doesn't amount to much. The ratio will be  1 to 1.3, something like that.

It's only when you get up to 0.8, 0.9 the speed of light that things get dramatic. Those kinds of speeds are achievable for particles in a particle accelerator, not for macroscopic objects.

(The amount of energy required to achieve high velocity skyrockets along with the degree of time dilation. Transferring that much energy to a macroscopic object isn't feasable, you end up evaporating the object.)

So what I can tell you is that in order to create a story where the protagonists experience significant time dilation effects you need to create another universe, one were such things do happen.

Later edit:
Time dilation kicks in *even later* than I thought. See this [light clock interactive animation](https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/more_stuff/Applets/Lightclock/home.html)

It is part of a larger collection of [interactive animations](https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/more_stuff/Applets/home.html) by Michael Fowler.

At 0.5 the speed of light the ratio is still only 8 to 9.
At 0.87 the speed of light the ratio is only 1 to 2

Comment: That is WILDLY helpful. I didn't even consider the energy input! Thanks so much!